# Using tab to indent a list rather than move to a new table cell in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, tabs

I work with tables in MS Word a lot, and inside those tables I often have numbered lists.

I would like to have the "TAB" key primarily function to increase indent, and then secondarily be used to tab between cells. Currently, MS Word "TAB" defaults to change cell, whereas I would want it to increase indent and then when I escape the numbered list, to regular in-cell formatting, use the "TAB" key to move to the next cell.

Any ideas?

MS Word 11 for Mac, but anything is helpful (even for windows versions, e.g. 2007)

Maybe this post isn't up to this forum's level, but I haven't found any answers elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can reconfigure Word in this manner.  You can indent inside a table cell by pressing CTRL+TAB though, if you didn't know.

Comment: Yeah, it does indent -- but doesn't indent the number level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pressing tab to indent a list moves to the next table cell](https://superuser.com/questions/521145/pressing-tab-to-indent-a-list-moves-to-the-next-table-cell)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you might be able to come is creating a quick macro for increasing indent and assigning it to a shortcut key that's close to the tab key.

To increase the indent, you'd use:

> `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent`

You might also want to create another macro for moving to the next cell in a table and assign it a different shortcut key. This way, instead of wanting to do two different things with Tab, you have them each assigned to their own shortcut key.

To move to the next cell, you'd use:

> `Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell`