# Pressing tab to indent a list moves to the next table cell

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a list (e.g., a bulleted list) in Microsoft Word. This list is inside a table cell.
When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to increase the indent, rather than increasing the indent, it moves the cursor to the next cell. When I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it just inserts a tab character without changing the indentation of the bullet (paragraph).

How can I turn this off, so it does not go to the next cell but rather just indents the list?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow Key</kbd> will demote your bullet inside a table, whilst <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow Key</kbd> will promote your bullet.

Comment: This works as a solution for adjusting indentation levels of a bulleted list in columns as well - just made my day!

Comment: On a Mac you can use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Right Arrow Key` to demote and `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Left Arrow Key` to promote.

Answer (score 5):

This is not, strictly speaking, an answer to your question, but rather a solution to your problem.  You can increase the indent by clicking on the “Increase Indent” button in the “Paragraph” group on the “Home” tab of the ribbon:

[image: the “Increase Indent” button in the “Paragraph” group on the “Home” tab of the ribbon]

**<edit>**
If you have [musophobia (fear of mice (and rats))](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_mice), you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
(if necessary, to select the “Home” tab of the ribbon) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>AI</kbd>.
**</edit>**

Comment: who wants to use a mouse when typing a word document. That's why keyboard commands exist. There is seriously no option to change the keys for these things?

Comment: All right, here you go.

Comment: It's not musophobia, though they do pass away when they around around me (something about boots stomping down on them, yes I'm redneckish). It's just that when you're editing a document and you're in a rhythm, going to the mouse is annoying (which is why I'm glad for full screen mode).

Answer (score 1):

When I have had to enter indents into tables I have always done this:

Enter some obscure text where you want your indents (Example: "TABTEXT")

Find and replace that text with a TAB by entering "^t" in the replace with box.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to turn this off entirely, but the best method I've seen is the one given by [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-tabs-in-a-table-838918a7-b279-454b-b2c0-9dd10b19c984) directly.

To indent inside a table cell, click in front of the text or numbers you want to indent, and then press `CTRL`+`TAB`.

Comment: CTRL+TAB is not working for lists as mentioned in the question.